# Ethernet NIC power usage on laptop?

Tags: fedora, power-management

I was wondering if the ethernet NIC draws any power at all when using Wifi? If it does, since I rarely use it, so is there a way to completely turn off the power from the device? I know some devices can be powered off by writing into some variable in the /sys folder. My guess is that unloading the driver module is not enough.

I'm running Fedora 16 with a 3.3 series kernel.

Comment: [Powertop](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/) can show you how much power various components of your system use. Whether you're using Wifi or not won't influence the power consumption of your wired NIC. A wired NIC consumes a lot less than Wifi (radio is energyvore), but I don't have hard figures.

Comment: [(Intel's) LessWatts.org](http://www.lesswatts.org/tips/) also contains some tips and tricks for powersaving (including Ethernet and WiFi).  (I guess it's less useful than Powertop, though)

Comment: You can use `ethtool` to turn off wake-on-lan for your wired adapter, using `ethtool -s eth0 wol d`. Doing so will lower the power consumption marginally when your laptop is sleeping, but the difference will be (imo) be negligible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Fedora 16 is [no longer supported](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle?rd=LifeCycle)